# AngularJS is treating dates inconsistently across browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I'm working on an AngularJS project that needs to handle dates and times. I've noticed that when I use $http.get() to fetch a JSON feed of dates, in Chrome AngularJS will transform the dates to match the client-side time zone, but in Internet Explorer the dates are not adjusted and yet the time zone information is still added as though it had been adjusted (a *terrible* way of doing things, since its effectively corrupting the date/time data).

Some examples:

Here's an example of the data:

```
[
  {
    "StartDate":"2014-05-21T09:30:00.000Z",
    "EndDate":"2014-05-21T13:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

So this is an event that goes from 21/03/2014 9:30am to 21/03/2014 1:00pm.

If I write a `$http.get()` like this:

```
$http.get('data_source')
  .success(function(data) {

    console.log(data);

  });
```

I get the following:

IE11: `Fri Dec 19 2014 09:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)`

Chrome: `Fri Dec 19 2014 20:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)`

Firefox: `2014-12-18T22:00:00.000Z`

The only one that looks remotely passable to me is Chrome - it's converting into the AEDT time zone by adding 11 hours to the UTC date.  IE is changing the time zone to AEDT without adjusting the time, and what Firefox is doing is a mystery, it seems to be treating the date as though it has been sent over the wire as UTC, and then converting it backwards to UTC.

Can someone explain to me exactly what on Earth is going on here?  Why the difference, and how can I standardise the date treatment?

Comment: Haven't used Angular too much so I can't comment with certainty, but I'm wondering if you've come across and whether it helps? http://aboutcode.net/2013/07/27/json-date-parsing-angularjs.html

If the demo works on all the browsers you're testing on, it might be plausible that this behaviour stems from the way you fetch your date information on the server side.

Comment: Oh this is embarrassing, but your link helped me identify the problem. I forgot I had implemented that solution already and THAT'S what was breaking it (I had modified the Regex expression). I set it back to what it says on that page and it fixed the problem in all three browsers. You are legendary!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call toString() method for your responce data.

```
$http.get('data_source').success(function(data) {
// if i understand you correctly and data seems is a field in your json in ISO format ~ 2014-05-21T13:00:00.000Z
    $scope.data = new Date(data).toString(); 
});
```

Seems it works in IE, Chrome and Firefox equally.